# Selecting k vectors with maximum spread out of a set of n vectors

Tags: algorithms, optimization, geometry

Given a set $\mathcal{V}$ of $n$ vectors, find a subset $\mathcal{V}_k = \mathcal{V} - \mathcal{V}_{n-k}$ containing $k$ maximally spread vectors.

Intuitively, these $k$ vectors should be spread as much as possible as directions on a unit sphere.

Formally, I think one needs to minimize the following formula:

$$\sum_{v_i, v_j \in \mathcal{V}_k}( 1 + \left< v_i, v_j \right>)^2,$$
where $v_i, v_j$ are unit vectors (after normalization).

Although the algorithm I need can be generalized to multiple dimensions, it can be kept simple 
(using only 3 dimensions).

Is there any link to principal component analysis in this case? (My intuition tells me the problem has been solved, but I can't find a related approach, nor a non-exponential complexity algorithm).